# При нажатии на ссылку стрелка переворачивалась на 90 градусов

Tags: javascript, html, css

К примеру, есть кнопка при нажатии на которую выпадает информация и рядом с ней есть стрелочка.
Сама кнопка выглядит вот так: "Смотреть >".
Объясните как сделать так, чтобы при нажатии на кнопку(Слово Смотреть) переворачивалась стрелка на 90 градусов

Answer (score 2):

```js
document.querySelector(".view").addEventListener("click", function(e) {
  document.querySelector(".arrow").classList.toggle("active");
});
```

```css
.active {
  color:red;
  transform:rotate(90deg);
}
.arrow {
  display:inline-block;
}
```

```html
<span class="view">Смотреть</span> <span class="arrow">&gt;</span>
```

```js
document.querySelector(".view").addEventListener("click", function(e) {
  this.classList.toggle("active");
});
```

```css
.view::after {
  content: ">";
  display: inline-block;
}

.view.active::after {
  color: red;
  transform: rotate(90deg);
}
```

```html
<span class="view">Смотреть </span>
```

Comment: даешь вариант с `::after`

Answer (score 2):

Вариант с `javascript` уже представлен господином @Igor

От меня вариант на голом `css`, основанный на `:focus`.

Чтобы фокус работал на элементе ему необходим `tabindex`, так же фокус сопровождается визуальным эффектом, который можно отключить при помощи `outline: none;`

```css
div.item, div.item div {
  background-color: white;
  padding: 5px;
  margin: 5px;
  cursor: pointer;
  box-shadow:1px 0px 4px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
}

div.item {
  outline: none;
  display: block;
  width: 125px;
}

div.item a {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 110px;
  outline: none;
  pointer-events:none;
  user-select:none;
}

div.item span {
   display: inline-block;
   transition: 200ms;
}

div.item div {
  opacity: 0;
  position: absolute;
  left: 140px;
  transition: 100ms;
  width: 100px;

}

div.item:focus span {
   transform: rotate(90deg);
}

div.item:focus div {
  opacity: 1;
}

div.item:focus a {
     pointer-events:all;
}
```

```html
<div class="item" tabindex="1">
 <a tabindex="2">Первый пункт</a><span>></span><br>
 <div>Подменю 1<br>Подменю 2<br>Подменю 3</div>
</div>

<div class="item" tabindex="3">
  <a tabindex="4">Второй пункт</a><span>></span><br>
  <div>Подменю 1<br>Подменю 2<br>Подменю 3</div>
</div>
```

Comment: а как сделать, чтобы стрелочка возвращалась в исходное положение при нажатии на тот же элемент

Comment: @DmitriyAndreevich при помощи вложенного элемента, который может принять на себя фокус, изменил ответ (обратный клик работает только по надписи, но можно переделать)